# If a continuous function is onto and has a sequentially compact domain, how do you show that the inverse function of a closed subset is also closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm toiling like mad trying to figure this out.

> $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is sequentially compact, and $F:K\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous and onto. Prove that if $A\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $F^{-1}(A)\subset K$ is closed.

### Attempt

Suppose that $A$ is closed.

Because $F$ is onto, every point in $A$ was sent there by a point in $K$.

Because $K$ is sequentially compact, it is closed and bounded, therefore $F^{-1}(A)$ is bounded.

Since $F$ is continuous, a sequence in a subset of its domain must converge to a point in that subset.

> I am convinced that $F^{-1}$ is bounded, but I'm not convinced that it is closed. I can imagine some sequence in $K$ that begins in $A$ but converges to a point on its boundary. I feel like the continuity of $F$ might remedy this issue, but I cannot see how

Comment: By continuity, $F^{-1}(A)$ is *relatively* closed. Since $K$ is also closed, ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm not familiar with the term "relatively" closed, so I don't suspect that I can use that as a justification.

Comment: If $K$ is a (sequentially) compact subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$, there is no continuous and onto function of $K$ onto $\Bbb{R}^m$ unless $m = 0$ (because $\Bbb{R}^m$ is not compact for $m \ge 1$). Aside from that, $F^{-1}$ maps closed subset to closed subsets iff $F$ is continuous by definition of continuity. So your question is very unclear.

Comment: Your question is not precise. I guess you want to show that $F^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $ A \subset \mathbb{R^m}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^m}$, then $ A' = \mathbb{R^m} - A = [r \in \mathbb{R^m}| r \notin A]$ is open in  $\mathbb{R^m}$. Since $F: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous, we then have that

\begin{equation}
F^{-1}(A') = [k \in K| F(k) \in A'] \; \; \; (\textrm{i})
\end{equation}
is open in $K$.

Note that 
\begin{equation}
F^{-1}(A) = [k \in K| F(k) \in A] \; \; \; (\textrm{ii})
\end{equation}

From equation (ii), it follows that

\begin{equation}
 K - F^{-1}(A) = [k \in K| k \notin F^{-1}(A)] = [k \in K| F(k) \notin A] = [k \in K| F(k) \in A']  \; \; \; (\textrm{iii})
\end{equation}

Comparing equations (i) and (iii) yields that $ F^{-1}(A') =  K - F^{-1}(A)$ .

Therefore, $K- F^{-1}(A)$ is open in $K$. Hence, $F^{-1}(A)$ is closed in K. Since $K$ is sequentially compact, it is closed in $\mathbb{R^n}$, so we have by a well-known theorem from point-set topology that $F^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^n}$.